# I get the same wrong output every time I try to make single image predictions in the example tf.layers. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, mnist

I've copied the code from the Tensorflow tutorial on using tf.layers basically verbatim, using the mnist training data and all that. The training and evaluation code, the prediction dictionary and the eval metrics are all left untouched. The problem I have is that I've been getting really irregular outputs on all of my own images that I've tried to feed to the network and get predictions on. There's two major problems I've faced so far:

1) Every image that I've fed to the network individually (after modifying them as shown in point 2) keeps giving me an output as: class [8]. That means that the network identifies it as the number '8', doesn't it? I've tried inputting a 4,7,0, etc but every time it gets read as an 8. The weird part is that after training, the network claims to have a very high accuracy rating but it doesn't even give me different outputs for different input digits. I'm wondering where exactly I've gone wrong.

2) I'm reading a .jpg image using the opencv imread function and converting it to float 64 first(with scikit-image) and then converting my image to a float 32 image with the numpy astype. I'm doing that so that the prediction actually goes through. For some reason, the network refuses to predict my regular uint8 image that gets read initially by opencv. The error message says that it will only take a float16, bfloat16 or float32 type image as the input.

Anyway, that's why I tried to tweak the original image as best I could and visually verified that the image doesn't appear to have changed compared to my original input image. Thus, with a float32 image input, the program gave me outputs but they were all the same(all were class [8]) and I'm thinking that I've made a mistake somewhere in the code.

Here's the source code, with my own tf.estimator.predict(). I am using Python 3.6.3 on Windows 10, both 64 bit if that's relevant.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import skimage


tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)


image1=cv2.imread("E:\Predict_images\image (5).jpg")
image2=skimage.util.img_as_float(image1)
image3=image2.astype(np.float32)
cv2.imshow('image1',image1)
cv2.imshow('image2',image2)
cv2.imshow('image 3',image3)

def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
  """Model function for CNN."""
  # Input Layer
  # Reshape X to 4-D tensor: [batch_size, width, height, channels]
  # MNIST images are 28x28 pixels, and have one color channel
  input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, 28, 28, 1])

  # Convolutional Layer #1
  # Computes 32 features using a 5x5 filter with ReLU activation.
  # Padding is added to preserve width and height.
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 28, 28, 1]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 28, 28, 32]
  conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=input_layer,
      filters=32,
      kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # Pooling Layer #1
  # First max pooling layer with a 2x2 filter and stride of 2
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 28, 28, 32]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 14, 14, 32]
  pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

  # Convolutional Layer #2
  # Computes 64 features using a 5x5 filter.
  # Padding is added to preserve width and height.
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 14, 14, 32]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 14, 14, 64]
  conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=pool1,
      filters=64,
      kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # Pooling Layer #2
  # Second max pooling layer with a 2x2 filter and stride of 2
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 14, 14, 64]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 7, 7, 64]
  pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

  # Flatten tensor into a batch of vectors
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 7, 7, 64]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 7 * 7 * 64]
  pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])

  # Dense Layer
  # Densely connected layer with 1024 neurons
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 7 * 7 * 64]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 1024]
  dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # Add dropout operation; 0.6 probability that element will be kept
  dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
      inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

  # Logits layer
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 1024]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 10]
  logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)

  predictions = {
      # Generate predictions (for PREDICT and EVAL mode)
      "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
      # Add `softmax_tensor` to the graph. It is used for PREDICT and by the
      # `logging_hook`.
      "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
  }
  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

  # Calculate Loss (for both TRAIN and EVAL modes)
  loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)

  # Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

  # Add evaluation metrics (for EVAL mode)
  eval_metric_ops = {
      "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
          labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])}
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)


def main(unused_argv):
  # Load training and eval data
  mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
  train_data = mnist.train.images  # Returns np.array
  train_labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
  eval_data = mnist.test.images  # Returns np.array
  eval_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)

  # Create the Estimator
  mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
      model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_convnet_model")

  # Set up logging for predictions
  # Log the values in the "Softmax" tensor with label "probabilities"
  tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
  logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
      tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

  # Train the model
  train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": train_data},
      y=train_labels,
      batch_size=100,
      num_epochs=None,
      shuffle=True)
  mnist_classifier.train(
      input_fn=train_input_fn,
      steps=20000,
      hooks=[logging_hook])

  # Evaluate the model and print results
  eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": eval_data},
      y=eval_labels,
      num_epochs=1,
      shuffle=False)
  eval_results = mnist_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
  print(eval_results)

  #Predict the result for new images
  pred_input_fn=tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": image3},
    shuffle=False)
  pred = mnist_classifier.predict(input_fn=pred_input_fn)
  print (list(pred))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()
```

This is the output given in the shell when i run this [It's an image of '1'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biWlc.jpg)  float 32 image through it:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 20000 into /tmp/mnist_convnet_model\model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 0.040543813.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2018-02-25-19:40:57
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /tmp/mnist_convnet_model\model.ckpt-20000
INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2018-02-25-19:40:59
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 20000: accuracy = 0.9717, global_step = 20000, loss = 0.09776818
{'accuracy': 0.9717, 'loss': 0.09776818, 'global_step': 20000}
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /tmp/mnist_convnet_model\model.ckpt-20000
[{'classes': 8, 'probabilities': array([4.6938831e-07, 3.4720117e-07, 5.8355248e-03, 7.6848278e-03,
   1.0895459e-06, 2.9385969e-06, 1.8598693e-06, 1.2013125e-09,
   9.8647296e-01, 5.2439987e-08], dtype=float32)}, {'classes': 8, 'probabilities': array([4.8870197e-07, 3.7765903e-07, 6.4324187e-03, 8.6945957e-03,
   6.3728720e-07, 3.2801559e-06, 1.5783016e-06, 1.3214099e-09,
   9.8486656e-01, 5.1528065e-08], dtype=float32)}, {'classes': 8, 'probabilities': array([5.9954516e-07, 3.2683863e-07, 7.1799601e-03, 8.4864357e-03,
   8.9206560e-07, 2.3296870e-06, 1.4247992e-06, 9.8779152e-10,
   9.8432791e-01, 7.0583980e-08], dtype=float32)}]
```

Edit: I'm just leaving a few more sample images I was using to try and make predictions. All of them show up as class 8.

[Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyEYO.jpg)  [Six](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBEVc.jpg)  [Three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktD7V.jpg)  [Four](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOxbo.jpg)

Comment: Using different kinds of preprocessing in your test data vs. training data is very dangerous. This is a bit of a shot in the dark (which is why I'm just commeting) but: Could it be that the "polarity" of your manually-read images is reversed compared to the Tensorflow MNIST set? I.e. in one version dark parts could be 0 and light parts 1, and in the other version it's the other way around. Could you test whether this is the case? If so, that would explain the nonsensical predictions.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Kinda. The program is now giving me different outputs for classes at least. The thing is, it's still not accurate enough. It's making too many mistakes. Anyway, you were right. I'd accidentally removed the invert color code from my program (for converting my regular images to MNIST style images) and putting it back is now giving me different predictions. Any idea as to how I can improve the accuracy of recognition though?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the problem as you described. I also wish someone can sharing his/her thoughts. The test images for training is black ground color, the figure is white. But once I predict the model with my data, it always shows the wrong number. I had tried to change background color but it predicts not right. Even the accuracy is pretty good after training. The image was gathered from web resources and drawn by myself, it is clearly readable and eligible. I pasted my predict code here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from cnn_mnist import cnn_model_fn
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Predict the image
#mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
#train_labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
#eval_data = mnist.test.images
model = cnn_model_fn
mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
     model_fn=model, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_convnet_model")

im = cv2.imread("D:\\tf_exe_2\\img_9.jpg")
#im2 = np.reshape(im, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
pred_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": np.float32(im)}, 
    shuffle=False)
pred = list(mnist_classifier.predict(input_fn=pred_input_fn))
for el in pred:
    print(el)
#print(next(pred))
```

And the result is wrong. It should be zero in the image content.

```
==================== RESTART: D:\tf_exe_2\cnn_predict.py ====================
INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_service': None, '_task_id': 0, '_session_config': None, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_tf_random_seed': None, '_num_worker_replicas': 1, '_model_dir': '/tmp/mnist_convnet_model', '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_task_type': 'worker', '_is_chief': True, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x000001B2CD51E588>, '_master': ''}
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /tmp/mnist_convnet_model\model.ckpt-21020
{'probabilities': array([0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32), 'classes': 2}
{'probabilities': array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.], dtype=float32), 'classes': 8}
{'probabilities': array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.], dtype=float32), 'classes': 8}
>>>
```

All the training steps and configuration are followed by the Tensorflow tutorial. Maybe it shall try to carry on modifying the training parameters, such as shuffle or another configuration?

Here is the cnn_mnist.py, exactly same as TensorFlow tutorial:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

#imports
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    """Model function for CNN"""
    #Input Layer
    input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1,28,28,1])
    #Convolutional Layer #1
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs = input_layer,
        filters = 32,
        kernel_size=[5,5],
        padding = "same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu)

    #Pooling Layer #1
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2,2], strides=2)

    #Convolutional Layer #2 and Pooling Layer #2
    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=pool1,
        filters=64,
        kernel_size=[5,5],
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu)
    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2,2], strides=2)

    #Dense Layer
    pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1,7*7*64])
    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
        inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

    #Logits Layer
    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)

    predictions = {
        #Generate predictions (for PREDICT and EVAL mode)
        "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
        #Add 'softmax_tensor' to the graph. It is used for PREDICT and by the
        #'logging_hook'
        "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
    }

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

    # Calculate Loss (for both TRAIN and EVAL modes
    loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)


# Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(
            loss=loss,
            global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

    # Add evaluation metrics (for EVAL mode)
    eval_metric_ops = {
        "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
            labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])}
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode, loss=loss,eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)

def main(unused_argv):
    #Load training and eval data
    mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
    train_data = mnist.train.images
    train_labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
    eval_data = mnist.test.images
    eval_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)
    #Create the Estimator
    mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_convnet_model")
    # Set up logging for predictions
    tensor_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
    logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
        tensors=tensor_to_log, every_n_iter=50)
    # Train the model
    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={"x": train_data},
        y=train_labels,
        batch_size=100,
        num_epochs=None,
        shuffle=True)
    mnist_classifier.train(
        input_fn=train_input_fn,
        #original steps are 20000
        steps=20000, 
        hooks=[logging_hook])
    # Evaluate the model and print results
    eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={"x": eval_data},
        y=eval_labels,
        num_epochs=1,
        shuffle=False)
    eval_results = mnist_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
    print(eval_results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()
```